# Is there a way to reference an environment variable in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, package.json, workspace

I want to ask everyone in my organization to add an environment variable in their systems pointing to the directory in their computers where the cloned packages from our organization live. Then, I want to point to that directory from our main project's `package.json` under `workspaces`. Is it possible to do that?

For example:

#### Package.json

```json
{
  "workspaces": [
    "$COMPANY/packages/*"
  ],
}
```